# Unable to upload data to mariadb container from docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using mariadb as mysql docker container and am having trouble uploading the data from the docker volume.

My database dockerfile is similar to the one posted at this link. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux_atomic_host/7/html/getting_started_with_containers/install_and_deploy_a_mariadb_container

Instead of importing the data as shown in the example in the above link, I would like to import it from a docker volume.

I did try using the docker-entrypoint.sh example where I loop through the files in docker-entrypoint-initdb.d but that gets me a myssql.sock error probably because the database is already shutdown from the dockerfile RUN command.

```
database:
  build:
    context: ./database
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - ./data/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=hell
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is this:

You want to get your schema trough mount volume, but you don't see in the database, right ?

First of all, if your intention is to use `mariadb` you can use the [MariaDB Official Docker Image.](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb)

So, with this way you avoid to use redhat images or custom building.

Second, You're copying this SQL, but you don't run a mysql import o dump or something like that. So, what you can do is to put in your docker-compose a command (for example):

```
database:
  build:
    context: ./database
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - ./data/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/data.sql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=hell
    - MYSQL_USER=test
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
  command: "mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql"
```

But is not the best way.

On the other hand, you can follow MariaDB documentation, set a mount volume, and in the first run, import data. And with the volume you don't have to run again imports. 
This is the mount that you have to put:

```
 /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql
```

Obviously, you can mount your sql file in a /tmp/ folder and thats it, and with `docker exec` execute sh and run it from inside.